# Earliest and latest onset of Huntington's Disease(Chorea)?

Tags: genetics

Huntington's disease can hit at any age, although it tends to hit middleaged people most often. What is the youngest and oldest person that has exhibited Huntington's?

Clarification: By oldest I mean with no prior symptoms until the age.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Huntington's disease may become symptomatic starting from as low as 2 years old [1] and rarely after 55 years old [2] (yet there is evidence of onset at 65 years old [3] and even more according to newer studies).

[image: Copyright © 2004, The American Society for Experimental NeuroTherapeutics, Inc.]

*Figure:* Copyright © 2004, The American Society for Experimental NeuroTherapeutics, Inc.
<sup>Richard H. Myers. [*Huntington’s Disease Genetics*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC534940/). NeuroRx. Apr 2004; 1(2): 255–262. doi:  10.1602/neurorx.1.2.255. PMCID: PMC534940</sup>

Factors [4]:

- CAG number (65%-71% of the variance in age of onset)
- siblingship (11%-19%)

> [...] paternal age is negatively associated with age at onset of HD *(Huntington's disease)*, particularly among subjects who inherit the mutant gene from grandfathers [5].

---

References:

1. Huntington's Disease Society Of America. *What is Huntington's Disease (HD)?* Available from http://www.hdsa.org/about/our-mission/what-is-hd.html (accessed 26.10.2014)
2. National Institute of Neurological Disorders and Stroke. *Huntington's Disease: Hope Through Research* Available from http://www.ninds.nih.gov/disorders/huntington/detail_huntington.htm (accessed 26.10.2014)
3. Myers RH, Madden JJ, Teague JL, Falek A. *Factors related to onset age of Huntington disease.* Am J Hum Genet. 1982 May;34(3):481-8. PMID: 6211092. Full text available from http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1685335/
4. Rosenblatt A, Brinkman RR, Liang KY, Almqvist EW, Margolis RL, Huang CY, Sherr M, Franz ML, Abbott MH, Hayden MR, Ross CA. *Familial influence on age of onset among siblings with Huntington disease.* Am J Med Genet. 2001 Jul 8;105(5):399-403. PMID: 11449389. Available from http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11449389
5. Farrer LA, Cupples LA, Kiely DK, Conneally PM, Myers RH. *Inverse relationship between age at onset of Huntington disease and paternal age suggests involvement of genetic imprinting.* Am J Hum Genet. 1992 Mar;50(3):528-35. PMID: 1531729. Full text available from http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1684271/

Comment: Any exact dates? Like a child of 612 days exhibiting it? Or a woman of 72 years?

Answer (score 1):

I first experienced Huntington's Chorea at 7-1/2 years of age. My father took me to Vanderbilt Hospital in Nashville, TN where it was confirmed by testing. I am now 71-1/2 years old, and have suffered Rheumatic Fever, a stroke, 4 heart attacks, and atrial fibrillation, along with many other less serious diseaes. I still have occasional bouts of Chorea, but am leading a mostly normal life.  During my earlier life at age 60, I completed a Bachelor of Science and an M.B.A. degree, so my reasoning faculties and ability to organize and study successfully are still intact. I may be on borrowed time, but don't worry about it.